# Matplotlib 1.3.1: plot(matrix("1,2,3")) -> RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matplotlib

I am working with python 2.7.5  using 
numpy.**version**: 1.7.1
matplotlib.**version**: 1.3.1
When I start "ipython2 --pylab" and execute the following code

```
x = matrix("1,2,3")
plot(x)
```

I get the error message

```
[...]
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/units.pyc in get_converter(self, x)
    146             except AttributeError:
    147                 # not a masked_array
--> 148                 converter = self.get_converter(xravel[0])
    149                 return converter
    150 
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py in __getitem__(self, index)
    303 
    304         try:
--> 305             out = N.ndarray.__getitem__(self, index)
    306         finally:
    307             self._getitem = False
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

In the older matplotlib version 1.3.0 this error was not present.

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanx, Klaus.

Comment: Does this patch https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2591 fix your problem?

Comment: Great! Yes, this fixed the problem: https://github.com/dopplershift/matplotlib/commit/cee4ba990c7e209561e4deec75452e9dc97c5a30  Thank you, tcaswell!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug which has been fixed on the master branch and the maintenance branch.

See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2591 and https://github.com/dopplershift/matplotlib/commit/cee4ba990c7e209561e4deec75452e9dc97c5a30

Comment: Is there a handy guide on how to update to the master branch? I'm using Anaconda and it hasn't been updated yet as far as I can tell.