# pyinstaller and matplotlib gets maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, recursion, matplotlib, anaconda, pyinstaller

This is my what I'm using:

- Python 3.4.3 windows distribution "Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit)".
- Matplotlib version 1.4.3
- Numpy version 1.6
- Pyinstaller version 3.0.dev0-py3.4

When I try to make an executable of a python file that makes a matplotlib figure, it issues a "maximum recursion depth exceeded". The code I want to compile is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I compile it using:

```
pyinstaller -F plottest.py
```

But I get the following error:

```
...
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 245, in visit
  return visitor(node)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 255, in generic_visit
  self.visit(value)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 245, in visit
  return visitor(node)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 249, in generic_visit
  for field, value in iter_fields(node):
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Full traceback located here: http://pastebin.com/3b62W1Lb

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042478/matplotlib-1-3-1-plotmatrix1-2-3-runtimeerror-maximum-recursion-depth)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just checked the units.py file and the bug you mention is already fixed in my version (matplotlib 1.4.3).

Comment: What as at the top of the call stack?

Comment: I added the full traceback: http://pastebin.com/3b62W1Lb

Answer (score 3):

Create a [spec](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html) file

```
pyi-makespec options name.py
```

Modify this spec by adding to start of file

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000) # or more
```

Build the executable file

```
pyinstaller options name.spec
```

Comment: I get the following error: ''pyi' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: @Lupacante it looks like you dont add "pyi" to PATH (environment variable)

Comment: The use of "pyi-makespec" is on this webpage: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/man/pyi-makespec.htm

and I modified the .sepc file according to @KirillDolmatov, and it worked :)